# Excel - Filter column based on values from a different column

Tags: excel, filter

I'm struggling with this for a while now.
I'm not very familiar with Excel and I've searched on the internet to find a solution to this but unfortunately no success so far.

What I want to do is to create a new column based on these criteria.
As you can see here

[image]

I want to create a new column based on column A but filtering out any cells that contain any of the words/set of words from column B.
Finally, the new column will have cells that will not contain any of the words/set of words found in column B.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Post reproduceable data here in post and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Excel365</kbd> you can use combination of below dynamic formulas.

```
=LET(x,XLOOKUP("*" & INDEX(C1:C3,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C1:C3))) &"*",A1:A5,A1:A5,,2),FILTER(x,NOT(ISERROR(x))))
```

[image]

Comment: I have Office 2019 and unfortunately is not working

Comment: Then VBA macro would be best choice.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that ... 
I will try to see if there is anyone who can help me with Office 2019